Selecting an Entry should change the Label's Text but it does not
I have one label and two entries. I want to make the label display the selected entry.
Right now selecting the second entry does not change the label.
What is the culprit?
Here is my code.
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject"
             x:Class="MyProject.TestPage"
             x:DataType="vm:TestViewModel"
             Title="TestPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="Entry1"  Text="Entry 1">
            <Entry.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SetSelectedEntryCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Reference Entry1}" />
            </Entry.GestureRecognizers>
        </Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="Entry2"
               Text="Entry 2">
            <Entry.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SetSelectedEntryCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Reference Entry2}" />
            </Entry.GestureRecognizers>
        </Entry>
  
        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedEntry.Text}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    public TestPage(TestViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = model;
        model.InitializeCommand.Execute(Entry1);
    }
}

It is annoying: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
public partial class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    Entry _selectedEntry;

    [RelayCommand]
    void Initialize(Entry selectedEntry)
    {
        SelectedEntry = selectedEntry;
        SelectedEntry.BackgroundColor = Colors.Pink;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    void SetSelectedEntry(Entry selectedEntry)
    {
        SelectedEntry.BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
        SelectedEntry = selectedEntry;
        SelectedEntry.BackgroundColor = Colors.Pink;
    }
}

Edit
Apparently it works on Android but it does NOT work on Windows.
Because I need a touch screen on Windows?

not necessarily the issue, but your VM shouldn't have reference to visual elements in it.  Instead, create a color property to bind the BackgroundColor to and update that property instead of directly modifying the UI

A variation @FreakyAli's answer, you can bind to the IsFocused property and use it in a DataTrigger as follows. This would minimize the amount of work your View Model needs to do since you can implement all the requirements in the View only, e.g.
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,0" Spacing="25">
    <Entry x:Name="Entry1" Text="Entry 1" />
    <Entry x:Name="Entry2" Text="Entry 2" />
    <Label x:DataType="Entry" Text="{Binding Text, Source={Reference Entry1}}">
        <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                x:DataType="Entry"
                Binding="{Binding IsFocused, Source={Reference Entry2}}"
                TargetType="Label"
                Value="True">
                <Setter x:DataType="Entry" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text, Source={Reference Entry2}}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
</VerticalStackLayout>

I do have a CommunityToolkit MultiMathExpressionConverter enhancement that has a simple XAML solution that helps solve your problem at increasing scale, e.g. for 3 Entry fields:
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,0" Spacing="25">
    <Entry x:Name="Entry1" Text="Entry 1" />
    <Entry x:Name="Entry2" Text="Entry 2" />
    <Entry x:Name="Entry3" Text="Entry 3" />
    <Label Text="{MultiBinding {Binding Text, Source={Reference Entry1}},
                               {Binding IsFocused, Source={Reference Entry2}},
                               {Binding Text, Source={Reference Entry2}},
                               {Binding IsFocused,Source={Reference Entry3}},
                               {Binding Text, Source={Reference Entry3}},
                               Converter={StaticResource MultiMathExpressionConverter},
                               ConverterParameter='x1 and x2 or x2 and x3 or x0'}" />
</VerticalStackLayout>

The above is based on being able to write the Label.Text expression as:
Label.Text = Entry2.IsFocused && Entry2.Text
          || Entry3.IsFocused && Entry3.Text
          || Entry1.Text

Or you could do something more conventional such as ConverterParameter='x1 ? x2 : x3 ? x4 : x0' which means:
 Label.Text = Entry2.IsFocused
               ? Entry2.Text
               : Entry3.IsFocused
                 ? Entry3.Text
                 : Entry1.Text

Help me out by voting on it:

The issue: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/2181
The PR: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/pull/2182


Does it work for more than two entries?

You can keep adding more DataTriggers, but that approach could quickly become messy. At that point, I would recommend moving to something different. For this latter case, I am sharing some a proposal change to the CommunityToolkit MultiMathExpressionConverter.

In your code above, x:DataType="Entry" is repeated twice in the label's children. Is it mandatory to repeat x:DataType for compiled binding to work in children even though it has been specified in the parent?

You should be using the Focused event for that with an EventToCommandBehavior
<Label Text="Whatever is your label text" x:Name="TxtLabel"/>
<Entry x:Name="MyButton">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                EventName="Focused"
                Command="{Binding YourCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference TxtLabel}}"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>

For more info check:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry?view=net-maui-9.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior

Here is my solution.I change the code.
-----Update-----
Here I use the EventToCommandBehavior,and it worked!
TestViewModel.cs

  public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") =>
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      public string Text1 { get => text; set {
              if (text != value) {
                  text = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged();  
              }
          } }

      public string text;
      public TestViewModel() {
          SetSelectedEntryCommand = new Command<Entry>((obj) =>
          {
              SelectedEntry.BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
              SelectedEntry = obj;
              SelectedEntry.BackgroundColor = Colors.Pink;
          }
          )
         ;
      }
    public ICommand SetSelectedEntryCommand { set; get; }
    Entry SelectedEntry { get =>entry; set {
              if (entry != value) {
                  entry = value;
                  Text1 = entry.Text;      
              }
          } }

      Entry entry;
      public void Initialize(Entry selectedEntry)
      {
          SelectedEntry = selectedEntry;
          SelectedEntry.BackgroundColor = Colors.Pink;
      }
  }

TestPage.cs
   public TestPage(TestViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = model;
        model.Initialize(Entry1);
    }

TestPage.xaml
       <VerticalStackLayout>
           <Entry x:Name="Entry1" Text="Entry 1" TextColor="Red">
               <Entry.Behaviors>
                   <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior  
                       EventName="Focused"
                       Command="{Binding SetSelectedEntryCommand}"
                       CommandParameter="{Reference Entry1}"
                       
                       />
               </Entry.Behaviors>
           </Entry>
           <Entry x:Name="Entry2"  TextColor="Red" 
Text="Entry 2">
               <Entry.Behaviors>
                   <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior  
           EventName="Focused"
           Command="{Binding SetSelectedEntryCommand}"
           CommandParameter="{Reference Entry2}"                      
           />
               </Entry.Behaviors>
           </Entry>
           <Label Text="{Binding Text1}" />
       </VerticalStackLayout>


Does it work on Windows?

Yes,it worked. I have updated the answer . Please give it a try.
